# "Не хотите (—) как хотите"

Tags: пунктуация

В поговорке "Не хотите (—) как хотите" нужно тире или запятая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы поставила тире, потому что первая часть указывает на условие совершения действия, названного во второй части: (если) не хотите - (то) как хотите.